# Can't find fragment by Tag for second time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs and each has a fragment. When switching from one to another using these like methods. First time is works fine and finds fragment by tag, but second time it can't find it and what is interesting when it tries to add fragment is drops me error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added:` so fragment is definitely somewhere there.

```
private void selectedSocialTab() {
            if (!mSocialTab.isSelected()) {
                mSocialTab.setSelected(true);
                mProfileTab.setSelected(false);
                mPlacesTab.setSelected(false);
                if (!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.make_grid)) {
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment frag = manager.findFragmentByTag("social");
                    if (frag == null) {
                        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.add(FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES, SocialScreenFragment.newInstance(), "social");
                        trans.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "NULL-social", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "NOT NULL-social", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES, frag);
                        trans.commit();
                    }

                } else if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.make_grid)) {
                    super.replaceFragment(SocialScreenLargeFragment.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont replace, add and show the fragment.

change:

```
trans.replace(FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES, frag);
```

to:

```
trans.show(frag);
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. There are no errors but fragment is not showing, maybe it is because I can't declare FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES like when removing?

Comment: Sorry.  The method takes only frag. Check  my updated post.

Comment: Yes, now it sees fragment all the time but when method show() executed nothing happens, maybe have some idea why?

Comment: Like you are setting setSelected(true/false).. When you show, you have hide it at some point. When you are showing the other fragment, you have hide other fragments and show the appropriate fragment.